# Poner cursor sobre un <input> al cargar la página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola a todos estoy buscando una forma de poner el cursor sobre un:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="gui-input" />
```

Esto tiene que ocurrir al momento de cargar la página y también cuando pase otro evento.
La pregunta es, cómo posiciono el cursor sobre el `input` que yo quiera?

Comment: Mil Gracias me ayudo mucho para mi proyecto de tesis.

Answer (score 14):

Puedes utilizar [HTML5 `autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). No necesitas Jquery ni otra librería javascript

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="gui-input" autofocus>
```

Si quieres utilizar JQuery puedes hacerlo así:

```
 $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
```

O puedes utilizar un ID:

```
<input id="miTexto" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="gui-input">

$("#miTexto").focus();
```

Comment: No sabía lo de **autofocus** excelente respuesta @Carlos.

Comment: en el caso del $("#miTexto").focus(); donde uso un id el input tiene que tener autofocus? y le afecta tener mas de 2 autofocus?

Comment: La etiqueta **<input>** que quieres ponerle autofocus *debe tener la propiedad id definida*, luego en el jquery le pones **$("#tuID").focus();**

Answer (score 8):

Podrías utilizar la función **[`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)** de Javascript.

Podrías generar una función y llamarla dentro de todos los sitios donde la necesites.

```js
function ponleFocus(){
    document.getElementById("texto").focus();
}

ponleFocus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
```

Answer (score -1):

Una vaina bien... resuelto

```
<script>

<input id="miTexto" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="gui-input">

$("#miTexto").focus();
```

Recuerden entrarlo en la etiqueta